# Dropbox FIle upload via API problem in PHP

Tags: php, api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I just stumbled over a problem using the Dropbox API.
Currently I am using the this lib: http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/

The problem is, if I upload a file I get a success but nothing arrives at the Dropbox.
I also "hacked" into the library and changed some of the post stuff. I can post it if you want.

Anybody got a solution for that?
Thanks!

//EDIT: I am using PHPs integrated OAuth functions
//EDIT2:

```
<?php

include "class/Dropbox/autoload.php";
$oauth = new Dropbox_OAuth_PHP("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
$dropbox = new Dropbox_API($oauth);

//re-login
if(isset($_SESSION["oauth_tokens"])) {
    $my->oauth->setToken($_SESSION["oauth_tokens"]);
}

//uploads itself to DB
if($dropbox->putFile( basename(__FILE__),  __FILE__ )) {
    echo "Success";     
} else {
    echo "Fail :(";
}
```

sure this is not the complete code but assume that the user is logged in. :)

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you're trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox for PHP, the library you're using to upload files to Dropbox, isn't maintained anymore and therefore may not function properly.

Try out [PHP Dropbox Uploader](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/PHPDropboxUploader). It is mentioned on the official Dropbox wiki.

Comment: I wanted to use the OAuth ability of Dropbox.